# How to extract a sibling img element based off the greatest input[type="number"] value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a unordered list, each li element has an image and a sibling input[type="number"](IMG - #), Im trying to append the image with the sibling with the highest number val(), when a button is clicked... $('#guessCheck')

My html code looks something like this

```
 <div id="checkedImageContainer" class="hidden col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3 style="color:black"><strong>Now rate your favorite Images!!(#1-10)</strong></h3>
                    <ul class="checkedImageList">
<li><image src="pics/hammer.jpg" name="hammer"><input id="rateInput" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10"><label id="RateButton">Rate</label></li>
<li><image src="pics/hardhat.jpg" name="hardhat"><input id="rateInput" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10"><label id="RateButton">Rate</label></li>
<li><image src="pics/paintbrush.jpg" name="paintbrush"" name="hammer"><input id="rateInput" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10"><label id="RateButton">Rate</label></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button id="guessCheck">That's MY Opini0n</button>
                </div>
<ul id="highestRated">
</ul>
</div>
```

I have this so far in my jquery but I'm getting a syntax error FOR MY IMAGE in my code and I know the src attr is wrong...

```
$('#guessCheck').on('click', function(){

let highestRating = $("input[type='number']").map(function() {
     return {ele: $(this), val: parseFloat(this.value)};
 }).get().sort((a,b) => {return b.val - a.val;})[0].ele;
 $('#guessImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
 console.log('removed hidden class on the #highestrated list');
 $('#guessImageContainer').append('<li><img src="' + highestRating.closest('img').attr('src') + '"><input id="guessMyValue" type="text"><button class="text-center" id="finishButton">Finish_Button</button><h2 class="text-center">Now Guess The Name Of The image</h2></li>');
```

});

[image]

In this case I would like to append the HAMMER img //\

This is the complete gameboard, and the the issue I'm running into when the image is appended from the "Thats My Opinion" button///

[image]

Comment: Might want to first change your code which works against `input[type='text']` to `input[type='number']`. See how must closer you get.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code:

- IDs must be unique. Change them to class.
- the selector by attribute must be changed to **[type='number']**
- open and close correctly strings
- sort the map result
- instead of **closest** you need **prev**
- don't add event handler inside event handler
- delegate correctly your events

The updated fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ko2qgr17/2/).

```js
var maxCheckedNum = 3;
$(document).ready(function () {
    // MAKE SURE YOUR USER WAS BORN BEFORE 2000
    //Once that is confirmed you can remove the class hidden
    $('#birthYear').on('click', function (e) {
        let userAge = $('#usersInput').val();
        if (userAge.trim() == '') {
            return;
        }
        if (+userAge <= 1999) {
            maxCheckedNum = +userAge;
            $('#gameRules').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#ageID').hide();

            $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= maxCheckedNum);
            /*
             THIS LINES ARE USELESS
             $('div>p').attr('id', "highlight");
             let userAgesLog = [];
             userAgesLog.push(+userAge);
             */
        }
        else if (+userAge >= 2000) {
            alert("You are of not of the age requirement to play this game")
        }
    });


    //Only allow users to check 3 models
    $('#imageNinpputList input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
        $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= maxCheckedNum);
    })

    //Push checked images to the second div when the confirm button is clicked
    $('#confirm').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#checkedImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#third-rule').removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $('#imageNinpputList input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (idx, ele) {
            $('.checkedImageList').append('<li><img src="' + $(this).prev('img').attr('src') +
                    '"><input data-old-value="1" class="rateInput" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10">' +
                    '<label id="RateButton">Rate</label></li>');
        });
    });
    // When input number is changed, loop through the other inputs and disallow them from being the same value as 'this input'

    //
    // delegate event on parent
    //
    $('.container').on('input', '#checkedImageContainer input[type=number]', function (e) {
        if ($('#checkedImageContainer input[type=number]').not(this).map(function () {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get().indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0) {
            $(this).val(this.dataset.oldValue);
        } else {
            this.dataset.oldValue = this.value;
        }
    });


    $('#guessCheck').on('click', function () {
        //
        // chose the right inputs
        //
        let highestRating = $('#checkedImageContainer input[type=number]').map(function () {
            return {ele: $(this), val: parseFloat(this.value)};
        }).get().sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.val - a.val;
        })[0].ele;
        $('#guessImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
        console.log('removed hidden class on the #highestrated list');
        $('#guessImageContainer').append('<li><img src="' + highestRating.prev('img').attr('src') + '"><input id="guessMyValue" type="text"><button class="text-center" id="finishButton">Finish_Button</button><h2 class="text-center">Now Guess The Name Of The image</h2></li>');
    });
});
```

```css
#confirm, #guessCheck {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #990000;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border-radius: 20%
}

#finishButton {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #990000;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: 33px border-radius : 20 %
}

#imagesConatiner {
    background-color: #f7f9f9;
}

#checkedImageContainer {
    background-color: #c0f9f9;
}

#guessImageContainer {
    background-color: #014747
}

.checkedImageList > img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 22px;

}

#ageID {
    background-color: #0d7272;
    height: 200px;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

#rulesList {
    font-size: 17px;
}

#gameRules {
    background-color: #af9607;
    color: white;
}

.rateInput {
    color: black;
}

#third-rule {
    color: black
}

.rateSelection {
    color: black;
}

#guessMyValue {
    color: black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <!--SECTION USER CONFIRMS THERE AGE TO VERIFY THE GAME BEING ABLE TO BE VISBLE TO THE USER -->
    <div id="ageID" class="text-center col-md-12">
        <h1>Let's make sure your good to play this Game , ENTER YOUR Birthyear :</h1>
        <input type="number" id="usersInput" min="1900" max="2018">
        <button id="birthYear" text="enterAge">enter_Age</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Section for users to read the rules of the game -->
    <div id="gameRules" class="hidden">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>Okay lets get started then here are the rules...</h1><br>
            <ol id="rulesList">
                <li style="color:black">Select your favorite images</li>
                <li><strong>YOU CAN ONLY SELECT THREE!!!</strong></li>
                <!--Don't display the third rule until the the user selects the favorite images -->
                <li style="padding-bottom:20px" class="hidden" id="third-rule">Now rate your favorite images.<strong>(DON'T
                    GIVE TWO IMAGES THE SAME RATING!!)</strong></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div id="gameBoard" class=".col-md-12">
            <div id="imagesConatiner" class="col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <ul id="imageNinpputList">
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=1" name="hammer"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=2" name="hardhat"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=3" name="paintbrush"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=4" name="screw"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=5" name="screwdriver"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=6" name="shovel"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=7" name="vest"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=8" name="wrench"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=9" name="cone"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <image src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=10" name="falshlight"/>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="tool">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button id="confirm">100% Sure!!!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The checked images arent pushed into li's,
                            or taken off display hidden until three models are clicked and
                            confirm button is clicked-->
            <div id="checkedImageContainer" class="hidden col-md-4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3 style="color:black"><strong>Now rate your favorite Images!!(#1-10)</strong></h3>
                    <ul class="checkedImageList">
                    </ul>
                    <button id="guessCheck">That's MY Opini0n</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Now display the picture the user thought was the most attractive -and ask the user to guess her nationality-->
            <div id="guessImageContainer" class="hidden col-md-4 ">
                <ul id="guessImageList">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [![this is the output im getting][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMCuj.png   I also changed the code a little to be...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ko2qgr17/ I copied my code to the fiddle, I'm assuming my codes not working because I'm using boostrap css, try copying my code from fiddle to your code editor and it should work

Comment: Thank you, I'm only 7 months into coding, my cousin is a full stack developer and he's trying to teach me as much as possible but his time is limited, so I appreciate the time you put in to help me out!!